# How much data can be passed as command line arguments?

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments

How many bytes can be sent as command-line argument when spawning a process under Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gahooa suggests a good article at http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/, but if that page disappears someday, here's the meat of the matter: to find the max length of your command line arguments try one of the following

```
* command: getconf ARG_MAX
* system call: sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)
* system header: ARG_MAX in e.g. <[sys/]limits.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

This snippet will tell you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const long value = sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX);
    printf("ARG_MAX: %ld\n", value);
}
```