# Is Python 'sys.argv' limited in the maximum number of arguments?

Tags: python, xargs, argparse, argv

I have a Python script that needs to process a large number of files. To get around Linux's relatively small limit on the number of arguments that can be passed to a command, I am using `find -print0` with `xargs -0`.

I know another option would be to use Python's glob module, but that won't help when I have a more advanced `find` command, looking for modification times, etc.

When running my script on a large number of files, Python only accepts a subset of the arguments, a limitation I first thought was in `argparse`, but appears to be in `sys.argv`. I can't find any documentation on this. Is it a bug?

Here's a sample Python script illustrating the point:

```
import argparse
import sys
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input_files', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

print 'pid:', os.getpid(), 'argv files', len(sys.argv[1:]), 'argparse files:', len(args.input_files)
```

I have a lot of files to run this on:

```
$ find ~/ -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 ls > filelist
748709 filelist
```

But it appears [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) or Python is chunking my big list of files and processing it with several different Python runs:

```
$ find ~/ -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 python test.py
pid: 4216 argv files 1819 number of files: 1819
pid: 4217 argv files 1845 number of files: 1845
pid: 4218 argv files 1845 number of files: 1845
pid: 4219 argv files 1845 number of files: 1845
pid: 4220 argv files 1845 number of files: 1845
pid: 4221 argv files 1845 number of files: 1845
...
```

Why are multiple processes being created to process the list?  Why is it being chunked at all? I don't think there are newlines in the file names and shouldn't `-print0` and `-0` take care of that issue? If there were newlines, I'd expect `sed -n '1810,1830p' filelist` to show some weirdness for the above example. What gives?

I almost forgot:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.2+
```

Comment: Weird problem. As another option you could of course just parse `filelist` inside your script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python sys.argv limitations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533704/python-sys-argv-limitations)

Comment: That's what xargs does. It still needs to call Python via the shell, so would have the same limitation on the arguments. Why not make your Python program take the `~/` and `-name *` parameters directly?

Comment: I had thought xargs somehow magically gets around the limited argument space problem.  Turns out it just forks off a separate processes with smaller chunks. Also turns out this behavior makes no difference in every application I've used xargs for, save this one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs` will chunk your arguments by default. Have a look at the `--max-args` and `--max-chars` options of `xargs`. Its man page also explains the limits (under `--max-chars`).

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't seen this before.  Any idea why the above command `find ~/ -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 ls > filelist` actually works?  It seems `ls` will be called several times, all writing (and not appending!) to the same file.  Perhaps the file is opened only once and it's xargs' output we're capturing?

Comment: The shell takes care of the redirection. `ls` actually outputs to `stdout`. Think of it as everything on the line inside parentheses and the redirection outside.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not seem to place a limit on the number of arguments but the operating system does.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533704/python-sys-argv-limitations) for a more comprehensive discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that you want from `find` is available from `os.walk`.

Don't use `find` and the shell for any of this.

Use `os.walk` and write all your rules and filters in Python.

"looking for modification times" means that you'll be using `os.stat` or some similar library function.

Comment: I agree in principle that doing all this from within python is the way to go, using os.walk, glob.glob, and os.stat. What I didn't know was that xargs still obeys the os limit and just makes multiple calls to the command with the remaining arguments.

Comment: "agree in principle" means "disagree".  Yet, you provide no reasons.  Here are the reasons why your decision is all-advice.  All Python is faster, simpler and more flexible.  Simpler because it's one language: Python.  Faster because it all runs in a single process (without swapping).  If you want more speed, use `multiprocessing`.  Finally, it's more flexible because you're not constrained by the weird limitations of `find`.  There is no downside to simplifying your application.

Comment: The application **normally** doesn't need to process thousands of files.  The work is usually done on a few dozen files (chromosomes); In a particular benchmark I'm testing, I have thousands of files. Perhaps my OP didn't make that clear.

Comment: @JakeBiesinger: Perhaps my comment didn't make it clear that `find` remains a bad idea if you're processing one file or millions.  Rather than repeat the reasons, I'll conclude by saying that there's no downside to replacing a `find` -based shell script with Python.  No downside.  Numerous advantages.

Comment: ofc there's a downsides, you're complicating your script with extra logic. instead of doing whatever operation it was doing on files, now it also has deal with how walk the file system. `find` is incredibly powerful and already does this exceedingly well

Answer (score 1):

xargs will pass as much as it can, but there's still a limit.  For instance,

```
find ~/ -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | grep total
```

will give you multiple lines of output.

You probably want to have your script either take a file containing a list of filenames, or accept filenames on its stdin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [xargs is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103163/1507124) by the number of chars of the calling arguments (maximum 2091281).

A quick test showed this ranges from 5000 files - 55000 files, depending on the length of the path.

The solution to get more is to accept piping in the file path through standard-in instead.

`find ... -print0 | script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

files = sys.stdin.read().split('\0')
...
```