# How to use a argument variable argv?

Tags: python, argv

I wrote the following command but I don't understand it.
`from sys import argv`
what is argv?
how to use it?
I wrote `sycript,a,b=argv`
but I am getting the error that need more than one value to unpack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from sys import argv - what is the function of "script"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666346/from-sys-import-argv-what-is-the-function-of-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'sys.argv' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455148/what-does-sys-argv-mean)

Answer (score 0):

`argv` - The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

`sycript,a,b=argv` gives you "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" because you have just run the script as `python <script_name.py>` without giving the two arguments.

Run the script like this: `python <script_name.py> <arg1> <arg2>`

For example,

`script.py`:

```
from sys import argv
arg,a,b=argv
print(arg,a,b)
```

run `script.py "arg1" "arg2"` and output:

```
script.py arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run the command by typing

```
python scriptname a b
```

By `scriptname` I mean the name by which you have saved the program code.

I hope this helps..