# for fi in sys.argv[1:]: argument list too long

Tags: python, bash, arguments, argv

I am trying to execute a python script on all text files in a folder:

```
for fi in sys.argv[1:]:
```

And I get the following error

```
-bash: /usr/bin/python: Argument list too long
```

The way I call this Python function is the following:

```
python functionName.py *.txt
```

The folder has around 9000 files. Is there some way to run this function without having to split my data in more folders etc? Splitting the files would not be very practical because I will have to execute the function in even more files in the future... Thanks

EDIT: Based on the selected correct reply and the comments of the replier (Charles Duffy), what worked for me is the following:

```
printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 python ./functionName.py
```

because I don't have a valid shebang..

Comment: This is not caused by python itself but by the os you use. Here is a related link to that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533704/python-sys-argv-limitations But anyway this is no best practice, try something like iced said.

Comment: (On a different point -- Python *modules* should have `.py` extensions. *Executables* written in Python shouldn't have any extension -- executables define commands, and you don't run `ls.elf` -- but instead should use a shebang to indicate their interpreter (`#!/usr/bin/env python` or such) and be marked executable (`chmod +x functionName`).

Comment: ...if you use setuptools, it'll automatically build and install wrapper executables for you that invoke the functions you want to be runnable; these wrappers, properly, are executable commands with no extensions.

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an OS-level problem (limit on command line length), and is conventionally solved with an OS-level (or, at least, outside-your-Python-process) solution:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ./your-python-program '{}' +
```

...or...

```
printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 ./your-python-program
```

Note that this runs `your-python-program` once per batch of files found, where the batch size is dependent on the number of names that can fit in `ARG_MAX`; see the excellent answer by Marcus Müller if this is unsuitable.

Comment: When I try the first I am getting the following error: sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ./removeHtmlAndUnuuencode.py '{}' +
find: ./functionName.py: Permission denied
find: ./functionName.py: Permission denied

Comment: When I try the second I am getting the following error: xargs: ./functionName.py: Permission denied
-bash: printf: write error: Broken pipe

Comment: The "permission denied" means what it says; you need to `chmod +x ./functionName.py`, and be sure it starts with a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`, or `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, as appropriate for your OS). Or `-exec python ./your-python-program {} +` to avoid the need for a shebang at all.

Comment: File "./functionName.py", line 68, in <module>
    with open("strip_" + fi, "w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'strip_./0000950144-08-001292.txt' the initial file is called 0000950144-08-001292.txt' and the processed should be called strip_0000950144-08-001292.txt but why does it try to add ./ and then fails ?

Comment: The "why" is "because that's how find works". Use the second formulation (with xargs) if your program can't deal with that.

Comment: I upvoted you for all the effort and what you're writing (many of which I can not understand :) ), hope we can solve this issue

Comment: from: can't read /var/mail/bs4
./functionName.py: line 2: import: command not found
./functionName.py: line 3: import: command not found
./functionName.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./functionName.py: line 6: `def unuuencode (iterator, collector=None, ignore_length_errors=False):'
from: can't read /var/mail/bs4 is the error I get when I try to use the second approach..

Comment: That looks like you don't have a valid shebang line in your script, so it's being treated as a shell script instead of a Python script. Make it `xargs -0 python ./your-script` if you don't want to fix that immediately (I've described what a valid Python shebang looks like elsewhere).

Comment: Awesome. Seems to be working (first 2 files are already produced so I suppose it should be ok now). Thanks @Charles Duffy! Could you please tell what "a valid shebang line in my script" would be? Thanks again !

Comment: A shebang line would be a first line starting with the characters `#!` and then the name of the interpreter to use to run the script (like `/usr/bin/python`). Thus, `#!/usr/bin/python` is an example of a valid shebang.

Comment: Ok perfect. I didn't know about this before. It seems like the path to where the compiler for Python is found so that when you call the function it knows which tool to use in order to properly execute the program. (If I understand correctly)

Comment: Thank you so very much for the flattery, by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

No. That is a kernel limitation for the length (in bytes) of a command line.

Typically, you can determine that limit by doing

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

which, at least for me, yields 2097152 (bytes), which means about 2MB.

I recommend using python to work through a folder yourself, i.e. giving your python program the ability to work with directories instead of individidual files, or to read file names from a file.

The former can easily be done using `os.walk(...)`, whereas the second option is (in my opinion) the more flexible one. Use the `argparse` module to give your python program an easy-to-use command line syntax, then add an argument of a file type (see reference documentation), and python will automatically be able to understand special filenames like `-`, meaning you could instead of

```
for fi in sys.argv[1:]
```

do

```
for fi in opts.file_to_read_filenames_from.read().split(chr(0))
```

which would even allow you to do something like

```
find -iname '*.txt' -type f -print0|my_python_program.py -file-to-read-filenames-from -
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' *.txt` is safer than `ls *.txt` -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Even better than that, though, would be `printf '%s\0' *.txt` and interpreting the NUL-delimited stream that generates -- otherwise, filenames with literal newlines (yes, they're legal in UNIX) will throw you off.

Comment: (`readlines()` is the wrong tool for the job for the same reason).

Comment: (This is kibitzing, though -- I like this answer more than most here; it'll have my upvote with some minor improvements).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: totally on your side here. Wait, I'll fix it

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: better now?

Comment: Much! In a case where my answer isn't suitable (for a tool that needs to operate on all files in a single invocation, for instance), or if one just wants the added efficiency of only doing a single fork/exec rather than one per (slightly-less-than-)`ARG_MAX`-sized batch of files, this is absolutely the right way to go.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to add that piece of information (i.e. the program being invoked on every single file isolatedly) to your answer more explicitely, btw.

Comment: Pardon? My answer doesn't execute once per file -- it runs the program on every _batch_, where batch size is dependent on the number of filenames that can fit inside `ARG_MAX`. But yes, that's worth mentioning, and I've made an appropriate edit.

Comment: (Using `find ... -exec ... {} ';'` would be once-per-file, but the newer [POSIX-standardized in 2006, IIRC] `-exec ... {} +` behavior removes that limitation).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ahhh nice, didn't know about ` {} +`, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it this way. Pass mask to your python script (e.g. call it as `python functionName.py "*.txt"`) and expand it using glob (https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

Comment: Sure, one _can_ do that, but it's not conventional/standard behavior on UNIX by any means. `ls` takes a list of filenames, not a wildcard (for instance); same for `tar`, and... well, pretty much everything other standard tool.

Comment: Also, good luck passing a file with a glob in its name that matches other files, without having your program operate against those other files as well.

Comment: ls will not for him in this case as well.

Comment: correct, `ls` will have the same failure -- but there's a standard way to solve this for `ls`, and that standard way will work here as well.

Comment: there is no "standard" way to do this except making `ls` part of the shell (so it can hook in before glob expansion). or expanding mask and piping file list to stdin, of course.

Comment: `xargs` is a POSIX-standardized tool. `find -exec {} +` was added to POSIX in 2006, so that too is literally standardized.

Comment: Also, `pax` is a POSIX-standardized tool, and that reads lists of filenames on stdin, another mechanism for doing this literally encoded in the standard.

Comment: ...and no, a shell couldn't work around this in any way other than how `xargs` and `find` already do -- the argument length limit is an OS limitation (on the size of the buffer used for both environment variables and command-line arguments), not a shell limitation. That limit is present even directly calling `execv()`-family functions from C.

Comment: there is no execv() if `ls` is just function inside shell (and sometimes it is, depends on shell).

Comment: Sure, but this limitation doesn't exist at all if it's a function inside the shell being called.

Comment: Oh! I get where you're going now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think about using `glob` module. With this module you invoke your program like:

```
python functionName.py "*.txt"
```

then shell will not expand `*.txt` into file names. You Python program will receive `*.txt` in argumens list and you can pass it into `glob.glob()`:

```
for fi in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
    ...
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functionName.py", line 64, in <module>
    for fi in glob.glob(sys.argv[1:]):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 27, in glob
    return list(iglob(pathname))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 38, in iglob
    if not has_magic(pathname):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 95, in has_magic
    return magic_check.search(s) is not None
TypeError: expected string or buff

Comment: ^ That's the error I am getting when I try to do what you're saying

Comment: Yes. I edited it now with assumption that only one file mask will be in use.